# Is there a way to maintain a session through links in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a project in python that scrubs websites and sends links to customers. I currently have functioning versions that simply relay information, but it would be much better if I could make it easier by sending post requests to the server. For example, I currently send a link to my users to a certain product. I want to know if, instead, I can perform post requests in my program and send them a link that is part of the same session where that POST has been done already (apologies for poor use of terms). Basically completing actions for them and sending it through a link?

Comment: Typically, sessions are managed via a sessionid cookie.  Is there a specific reason you want to do it another way?

Comment: Can you give us some real examples? And an example of your python code

Comment: @JohnGordon , do you mean I would send this id through the link to my customers, so their cart would be the same session as my cart?